# How to make field group (tabs) visible for anonymous users?

Tags: 7, users, entities

In D7 how to make field group (tabs) visible for anonymous users?

I have installed and configured, I am able to view the tabs on add content page, but the tabs are not visible for anonymous users. And there are no permissions to enable the display for anonymous users.

Comment: Do you mean field group or vertical tab? They are different modules.

Comment: I mentioned field group, using field group we can have tabs vertical or horizontal ways

Comment: seems like this dose not work on D7 at all. I tried everything I can do, but could not get this enabled for anonymous users :(

Comment: I did try on my test site. It was ok.

Comment: Have it working. (But for some reason my answers are blocked on http://drupal.stackexchange.com)  ;(

Here are the steps:
1. Enable the field_group module
2. Go to specific content type
3. Click on manage display block
4. Add field group (Any specific type of group first, eg: Horizontal tab group )
5. And then add another field group (this time select item, eg: Horizontal tab item)
6. Drag and drop Horizontal tab item under Horizontal tab group.
7. Drag and drop the field that you would like to display under that particular tab item

Click save at the bottom of page.